# Adding exception handling to while loop in Python

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, while-loop, try-except

How would I add exception handling to this while loop?

I've can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I've tried... Try: except: but to no avail.

Specifically this is a file selector. When the user doesn't select a file or selects the wrong filetype I want to keep the program open, let them know of the error and allow them to select a different file, rather than having the program quit.

```
while True:     
        
        event, values = window.read()

        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
                 break
                
        if event == '  Ok  ':
                 # If OK, then need to add the filename to the list of files and also set as the last used filename
                sg.user_settings_set_entry('-filenames-', list(set(sg.user_settings_get_entry('-filenames-', []) + [values['-FILENAME-'], ])))
                sg.user_settings_set_entry('-last filename-', values['-FILENAME-'])
                lastFile=values['-FILENAME-']
                break
        
        elif event == 'Clear History':
            sg.user_settings_set_entry('-filenames-', [])
            sg.user_settings_set_entry('-last filename-', '')
            window['-FILENAME-'].update(values=[], value='')
                      
window.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use try/except within a while loop and have it exit or silence the exception as you would like. See this sample snipped below:

```
In [111]: while True:
     ...:     print('Hello')
     ...:     try:
     ...:         raise Exception()
     ...:     except Exception as e:
     ...:         print('Exception raised')
     ...:         raise e
     ...: 
Hello
Exception raised
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-c0ec85d9988a> in <module>
      5     except Exception as e:
      6         print('Exception raised')
----> 7         raise e
      8 

<ipython-input-111-c0ec85d9988a> in <module>
      2     print('Hello')
      3     try:
----> 4         raise Exception()
      5     except Exception as e:
      6         print('Exception raised')

Exception:
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this... the problem is, I have break clauses and multiple if statements so  I don't know how to arrange it all within my loop to ensure it works. Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you posted a fuller example of what you're trying to build. You can definitely add a try/except to a while loop to exit when necessary, which answers your main question.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I have got this working now. Thank you!